Hosting a Windows Service using .NET Core
I'm porting an existing .NET Framework Application which was spread about various Windows Services to .NET Core. It is not that the applications should run autonomously but in the context of ASP.NET Core.
Now it seems like Microsoft has 2 ways for creating Service applications, one is akin to way before using ServiceBase class which enables operations on Events like when the service is started or stopped.
(Old but still valid example here: https://www.coreprogramm.com/2019/08/how-to-create-windows-service-in-net.html)
And then there is a new way of doing it using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services (BackgroundService)

The background service is closely aligned for being used with ASP.NET Core, but it does not implement some features like the pausing and resuming of services, like the ServiceBase did.
Is it bad practice to try to control the service behavior with a secondary wrapper using ServiceBase or would you completely stick to BackgroundService? Is there maybe a way to easily replicate the old way of doing things?

Obvious first question: Do you actually need "the old way"? If the only perceivable difference to you is being able to pause and resume as part of the service interface - what do you need that for? And: can and is it possibly even better to do that in a different way?

You might also consider using 3rd party solutions like, for instance, TopShelf.  This is a nuget package that allows you to build plain old console apps and then install and run them as a windows service with just a few lines of configuration code.
I've used them before and it was very simple and easy

Assuming you would have Pause/Resume for your windows service how should that be enforced on the IHost derivate you need for running Asp.Net Core? I'm not aware that those are pauseable. Standard walkthrough

@Fildor thanks I will reconsider that. to Zohar Peled, thanks also to you, I will look into that library too as part of the consideration how to migrate in the most effective manner. to Ralf Alright, yea I came to the same conclusion but I guess it will be a minimal working example first.

Long back I did using Tofself and Fluentscheduler. I wrote a article for the same that talks about step by step implementation of that. You can have a look here
